# Error timeout get HTTP request golang

Tags: go

I tried to get html source from [Reddit](http://reddit.com) with Golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    timeout := time.Duration(5 * time.Second)
    client := http.Client{
        Timeout: timeout,
    }
    resp, _ := client.Get("https://www.reddit.com/")
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println("HTML:\n\n", string(bytes))
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    var input string
    fmt.Scanln(&input)
}
```

First attemp was good. But at the second time it ran into an error:

```
<p>we're sorry, but you appear to be a bot and we've seen too many requests
from you lately. we enforce a hard speed limit on requests that appear to come
from bots to prevent abuse.</p>

<p>if you are not a bot but are spoofing one via your browser's user agent
string: please change your user agent string to avoid seeing this message
again.</p>

<p>please wait 6 second(s) and try again.</p>

    <p>as a reminder to developers, we recommend that clients make no
    more than <a href="http://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API">one
    request every two seconds</a> to avoid seeing this message.</p>
```

I tried to set delay but it still not work.
Sorry about my bad English.

Comment: The response from reddit seems quite comprehensible. Read it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Reddit doesn't want automatic scanner\grabbers on their site and has a bot-protection mechanism.
Here's a recommendation from them:

> one request every two seconds

Just add a delay between requests.

Comment: I set timeout. But it still not work
    timeout := time.Duration(5 * time.Second)
        client := http.Client{
            Timeout: timeout,
        }

Comment: Not timeout, but a delay. Try to add `time.Sleep(2000 * time.Millisecond)` before `Get`.

Answer (score 0):

`timeout` serves a different purpose. timeout is an upper limit for a routine to run. What you need is `sleep` between subsequent requests.

```
time.Sleep(6 * time.Second)
```

Comment: I add time.Sleep under Get and ReadAll but still not work

Comment: I've modified some bits and this piece of code works fine for me: https://play.golang.org/p/DskqvYB_9B